# _POST[] remove all + sign

Tags: java, php, post

I have a simple java code that send a POST request to a php file, for example i send "test+-" when i echo the post it return "test -" why the + is removed?

The java code convert the text to bytes, maybe there is the sign lost?

```
OutputStream out=conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(test.getBytes());
```

Thx for the help.

**Update:**

I tyed `out.write(URLEncoder.encode(test).getBytes());`, thx to @Marek but with this method the php don't recognizes the POST text

**Edit:**

Found solution, based on @HugoDelsing answer i just replace in the php class all spaces with a + and solve the error.

`$test = str_replace(' ', '+', $test);`

Comment: the `+` sign is the encoded version for a `space`.

Comment: "Re-encoding" 1 character on the php side will not fix the initial encoding issue. Also you now cannot post empty spaces without them getting swapped incorrectly to plus signs.

Comment: @Phil_1984_ That what i'm sending is just a RSA encrypted text so there cannot be a space, or i thinks so.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just write post stream, you have to encode it, for example using [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html):

```
out.write(URLEncoder.encode(test).getBytes());
```

It's not clear what encoding you are using, supply it as second parameter.

Comment: When i put it as the same way `            OutputStream out=conn.getOutputStream();
            out.write(URLEncoder.encode(querry.getBytes(), type));` i get a error that a byte[] canot be converted to string, if i let it as stryn then the output stream says that it need to be byte[]

Comment: Right, `getBytes()` should be on return value, updated answer.

Comment: ok i Tryed it, its return my that there are no variables set in the _POST['test']